# Force uninstallation of extension

Tags: extensions

Is there anyway to uninstall an extension (force), even if there are errors during the process like folder not found etc...

Comment: By "force an uninstall of an extension" are you referring to removal from the database?

Comment: @NeilRobertson Yes.

Answer (score 1):

**Manual Removal**

The removal of an extension sometimes fails.

You can usually complete the removal manually by:

- removing the extension files (see the xml manifest file included in the installation file for the list of files and folders that the extension installs) using the File Manager in your hosting control panel or an FTP client
- removing the record in the extensions table using phpMyAdmin or similar
- removing any database tables associated with the extension

Some extensions may also be associated with records in the assets, schemas, menu and other database tables.

**Reinstall/Remove**

Another option that sometimes works when items are missing and removing an extension fails is to reinstall a fresh copy over the top of the existing install to ensure all the items are present. You can then retry the removal and it may have a better chance of completing successfully.

Comment: Thank you. Any plans to add a new feature to Joomla that can take care of such a process? Integrity checks of some kind.

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a folder not found, then just create the folder manually. You can always download the extension and extract it and then uninstall it.

Comment: True, but other issues can also arise during development that makes the installation abort in the middle. Thanks, though.